# How pass exception raised in decorator to function decorated?

Tags: python, decorator

I'd like that the function decorated can catch the exception raised by its decorator

```
def decorator(func):
   def _decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
       if condition:
           return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
       else:
          """
          THIS EXCEPTION CAN'T BE CAUGHT FROM FUNCTION DECORATED
          """
          raise LimitReached 
return _decorator
```

How can I head on?

Comment: The only way to be able to catch an exception is with a `try` block.  A `try` block could appear anywhere in `func()`.  What tells the decorator where to throw the exception?

Comment: You can't. The `func()` call is *already completed*. How would this work anyway, at which point in `func()` should the exception be raised?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? It makes no sense to me to inject an error into the function you're wrapping.

Comment: If `func()` is a *generator* or *coroutine* you can raise an exception in that flow, but only at the point where it is paused. You don't seem to be talking about generators however.

Comment: You can pass an error as argument and then (if it's not none) raise that error (if you can modify the original function. But that's not really useful. You could also probably do something via ast transformations, but that's really hacky. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done. The decorated function is an inner scope and can't catch exceptions raised in the decorator outer scope. Think about the three steps involved in running the code.

(1) The decorator runs some code before the decorated function is called... the decorated function can't catch any exceptions there because it hasn't run yet.

(2) The decorator calls the decorated function... now the decorator can't raise an exception because it isn't running.

(3) the function returns and the decorator code runs again... the decorated function can't catch anything because its aleady completed execution.

(edit)

There is a solution to the problem. `func` knows that it should be catching some sort of exception. This same `func` could be written to have a parameter that tells it that it is in an error condition. I'm not sure this is the best solution (is a decorator even needed here?) but I could be convinced...

```
def func(p1, p2, kw1=None, errorstate=None):
    if errorstate:
        do_error_path()
        return

def decorator(func):
   def _decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
       if condition:
           return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
       else:
          kwargs = kwargs.copy()
          kwargs['errorstate'] = LimitReached()
          return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
return _decorator
```